# Interactive table

Tags: jquery, interactive

I need a interactive table. By word interactive I mean "I should be able to add rows and delete them from table".

Above table I have input fields. So script should take value of each input field and add to table. But in the table should be a cross (for deleting rows), and once I click on it row gets deleted.

Also I must somehow pass all rows to PHP script.

How can I do all of that?

Answer (score 0):

For the add/remove rows part : [`append`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append) [`remove`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove)

Getting values of inputs is pretty obvious using [`val`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val).

Write some code and if you're stuck again, come back and edit your post with your code.